# Is there a way to send IOS application parameters after installation?

Tags: ios

My user presses the following link to download my application:

`itms-services:///?action=download-manifest&url=http://aaa.com/myApp.plist?regCode=12345`

Can the application get the "regCode" parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. iOS will download and install the IPA referenced in your plist, but will not pass along any parameters.

Depending on the problem you're trying to solve, you could make slightly different builds with different targets, or have the user login in-app.

Comment: My problem is that I have two modes in my applications that the user is not suppose to be aware of. And according to the parameter in the download link the application will start in the desired mode.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make two builds of your app, and point the user to one of two separate .plist files depending on which version you want them to have.